# Embedded Google Calendar in Fancybox v2 shows blank on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, google-calendar-api, fancybox-2

I have just embedded a google calendar into my site as a fancybox pop up.  It works as expected on desktop, but shows up blank on iphone in both landscape and portrait.

HTML

```html
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=SOURCE REMOVED;color=%231B887A&amp;ctz=Australia%2FSydney" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></a>
```

SCRIPT

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        //    fancybox
          jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
 'type'   : 'iframe',       // tell the script to create an iframe
  });
}); 
    </script>
```

Also just discovered that the calendar displays as a blank fancybox in Chrome, and the fancybox does not even open on safari on mac. (spinning wheel) I use this same code to open youtube videos, soundcloud playlists and html files on the same site.  Can't work out why the calendar is not working on some platforms...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the Calendar I was embedding was not made public and therefore not showing on some browsers.  Strange that it worked on Firefox(mac) and even iPad without being made public.